# Integrating and fitting coupled ODE's for SIR modelling

Tags: python, scipy, model, curve-fitting

In this case, there are 3 ODE's that describe a SIR model. The issue comes in I want to calculate which beta and gamma values are the best to fit onto the datapoints from the `x_axis` and `y_axis`values. The method I'm currently using is to integrate the ODE's using `odeint`from the `scipy` library and the `curve_fit` method also from the same library. In this case, how would you calculate the values for beta and gamma to fit the datapoints?

P.S. the current error is this: `ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (3,) (14,)`

```py
#initial values
S_I_R = (0.762/763, 1/763, 0)

x_axis = [m for m in range(1,15)]
y_axis = [3,8,28,75,221,291,255,235,190,125,70,28,12,5]


# ODE's that describe the system
def equation(SIR_Values,t,beta,gamma):
    Array = np.zeros((3))
    SIR = SIR_Values
    Array[0] = -beta * SIR[0] * SIR[1]
    Array[1] = beta * SIR[0] * SIR[1] - gamma * SIR[1]
    Array[2] = gamma * SIR[1]
    return Array


# Results = spi.odeint(equation,S_I_R,time)

#fitting the values
beta_values,gamma_values = curve_fit(equation, x_axis,y_axis)
```

Comment: Please check your math first or provide more details to your question. You've got an ODE with two states and three equations, so which of the two ode states do you want to fit against your given datapoints x_axis and y_axis? It's also highly recommended to use solve_ivp instead of odeint nowadays.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```py
# Starting values
S0 = 762/763
I0 = 1/763
R0 = 0


x_axis = np.array([m for m in range(0,15)])
y_axis = np.array([1,3,8,28,75,221,291,255,235,190,125,70,28,12,5])
y_axis = np.divide(y_axis,763)

def sir_model(y, x, beta, gamma):
    S = -beta * y[0] * y[1] 
    R = gamma * y[1]
    I = beta * y[0] * y[1] - gamma * y[1]
    return S, I, R

def fit_odeint(x, beta, gamma):
    return spi.odeint(sir_model, (S0, I0, R0), x, args=(beta, gamma))[:,1]

popt, pcov = curve_fit(fit_odeint, x_axis, y_axis)
beta,gamma = popt
fitted = fit_odeint(x_axis,*popt)
plt.plot(x_axis,y_axis, 'o', label = "infected per day")
plt.plot(x_axis, fitted, label = "fitted graph")
plt.xlabel("Time (in days)")
plt.ylabel("Fraction of infected")
plt.title("Fitted beta and gamma values")
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

As [this example](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.15.1/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.curve_fit.html) from `scipy` documentation, the `function` must output an array with the same size as `x_axis` and `y_axis`.

Comment: In this case, the `x_axis` data and the `y_axis` data have the same length (which is 15), or do you mean something else?

Comment: I mean length of function's output must be 15. in your code, function's output is an array with 3 elements. it must be 15 elements. @Gerard